# How to set the scope in Vue.js i18n with $t?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm trying to set the scope for a translation to 'parent' while using the $t() function, but I'm unable...

I know it is posible to set it up when using the tag syntax...

```
<i18n-t :keypath="label" scope="parent"> </i18n-t>
```

Is there any way I can do the same with the $t function?

Comment: It's probably on my side but I don't know what is an i18n scope.

Comment: @kissu It is where you can look for a translation... you can have a local scope (that applies to you component), a parent scope (that applies to the local scope of your component + the local scopes of your parent components) and a global scope...

Comment: Ooooh. I always use a global path for everything since it provides a nice auto-completion in VScode. Having a `parent` scope seems to be highly coupled to the parent component, not sure that there is any benefit since if you move it, you have a lot of rewrite to do. A local scope can be nice in some cases. Regarding [the doc](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/injection.html#componentcustomproperties), there is no mention as of a `scope` param but maybe you can pass a `key/value` pair to the `$t` object and see if it works. Otherwise, you can also try to ask on Github's issues/Discord.